# How do I specify a ticking function in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft

So I know how to make a normal function, but is there a way I can make a function run on every tick without prior setup in the world? I'm on Bedrock edition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an animation controller to the player entity. Do this by adding

```
      "scripts": {
        "animate": [
          "animation"
        ]
      },
      "animations": {
        "animation": "controller.animation.function_runner"
      }
    },
```

in the player.jsou file, right after "is_experimental": false, and before "component_groups": {

After that, you need to create the actual animation controller for the player. First, ceate a folder named animation_controllers in your behavior pack directory. Create a file named function_runner.json and put this code inside:

```
{
    "format_version": "1.10.0",
    "animation_controllers": {
        "controller.animation.function_runner": {
            "initial_state": "1",
            "states": {
                "1": {
                    "transitions": [
                        {
                            "2": "1.0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "on_entry": [
                        "/function yourfunctionhere"
                    ]
                },
                "2": {
                    "transitions": [
                        {
                            "1": "1.0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "on_entry": [
                        "/function yourfunctionhere"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Change yourfunctionhere to the actual name of your function, save and you should be done. If you want me to explain what is happening, let me know.

Edit: I forgot to mention that after doing so, you just need to create the actual function, add a manifest.json and compress all files using zip, then change the extension of the file to .mcpack. You probably already knew this, but just in case you didn't, I am leaving this here.